# Invert and flatten a dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have something that looks like:

```
{
  "Item1": ["1a", "1b", "1c"],
  "Item2": ["2a"],
  "Item3": ["3a", "3b"]
}
```

What I want is this:

```
{
  
  "1a": "Item1", 
  "1b": "Item1", 
  "1c": "Item1",
  "2a": "Item2",
  "3a": "Item3", 
  "3b": "Item3"
}
```

I've been able to do this, but just wondering if there is a more concise LINQ way?

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> items = new Dictionary<string, string[]>(...);
Dictionary<string, string> endResult = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // This is correct

var reversed = items.ToDictionary(x => x.Value, x => x.Key);

foreach (var item in reversed)
{
    foreach (var inner in item.Key)
    {
        endResult.Add(inner, item.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: More concise doesn't necessarily mean better though.

Comment: The `ToDictionary` seems unnecessary. Just `foreach` over `items`.

Comment: I will go for the foreach. it's easier to read. At least the same perf. Easier to debug. It's literally 3 lines of code. Variable name in the foreach is clearer, and consistent from the iteration to the insertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, string> endResult = items.Select(o => o.Value.Select(v => new { Value = v, Key = o.Key }))
                                            .SelectMany(o => o)
                                            .ToDictionary(o => o.Value, o => o.Key);
```

Comment: Can't you use `.SelectMany(o => ...).ToDictionary` rather than `.Select(o => ...).SelectMany(o => o).ToDictionary`?

Answer (score 1):

To add a slightly more concise way, taking advantage of the fact that `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` has a constructor which accepts an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`:

```
Dictionary<string, string> result = new(
    input.SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value.Select(v => KeyValuePair.Create(v, kvp.Key))));
```